# Displaying barcode in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to display the barcode in the SSRS report.

I have created a field in the report for barcode in the visual studio and changed the font type to BC C39 3 to 1 Wide format. The corresponding text that I have used to display is "hellobarcode".

Whenever I generate the report, it is not displaying the barcode but the text only. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When a particular field in the report is an hyperlink to other report (for drilldown purpose), it will get the default font format so that it won't display barcode font. I removed the hyperlink from the field and it showed the barcode.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to check for this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the font is installed on the SSRS server.

Comment: The font is installed. Now the encoded code is being displayed in plain text but not in barcode.

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of is to redeploy the particular report in question and re-install the report.  I didn't solve this particular error but was aware of a solution internally at our company.

Comment: Don't forget that the SSRS service delivering the report may not be installed on the same machine as the Ax service.  "is not displaying the barcode but the text only." so perhaps you have installed the font but not restarted the SSRS service?  Finally, check if the font is embedded in the PDF reports, if that is what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Go look how others have done it: `\SSRS Reports\Reports\WMSLocationLabel`

Your barcode font should be installed wherever the font is used, and usually is by the AX installer.

Some barcodes are only for numeric data, in others alphanumeric is okay.
Also most fonts requires the field to be preprocessed (fx. a star in front and end). 
The [Barcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/barcode.aspx) class takes care of that.

Comment: Whenever I give the UPC A value of 075678164125, it is encoded to .075678/;@>;<?:. and is being displayed in the report but the real bar code is not being displayed. I went and look through \SSRS Reports\Reports\WMSLocationLabel but they are using the autoreport feature. I am trying to accomplish this using precision design. Any further insight?

Comment: It should not matter whether you are using autoreport or precision design.

Comment: I figured out the problem. When a particular field in the report is an hyperlink to other report (for drilldown purpose), it will get the default font format so that it won't display barcode font. I removed the hyperlink from the field and it showed the barcode.