# Add a barcode field in AX 2012 SSRS report

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-2012

I want to add a packingSlipId Barcode field in SalesPackingSlip report.
Which is best way to do it?

Should I just add a packingSlipId field and change it's font and font size or I have to do some codings in ax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find these links useful:

[Display Barcode in SSRS report [Dynamics AX 2012, X++]](https://dynamicsaxgyan.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/display-barcode-in-ssrs-report-dynamics-ax-2012/)

[Displaying barcode in SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318891/displaying-barcode-in-ssrs-report)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to do it. You just need to add packingSlipId field to the report as text and then set the font to a barcode font.

You can use this one or just find another free barcode fonts:
http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/

Just remember if you're gonna use Code 39, you need to begin and end with an asterisk (*)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code in your RDP class and for this fields in report set font as barcode font.

```
Barcode         Mybarcode;
Mybarcode= BarcodeCode128::construct();
Mybarcode.string(true,_yourtable.packingSlipId );
Mybarcode.encode();
_yourTmpTable.Barcode= Mybarcode.barcodeStr();
_yourTmpTable.BarcodeHR= Mybarcode.barcodeStrHR();
```